# Recursive Queries

Tags: mysql, recursion

I have a problem with Recursive Queries:
In the table `partlist` are two fields: `article` and `part`. An article can have more than one part and a part can also have other parts.

For example:

- `Article 0` has parts `article 1` and `article 2`
- `Article 1` has parts `article 1a` and `article 1b`
- `Article 2` has parts `article 1a` and `article 2b`
- `Article 2b` has parts `article 3a` and `article 3b`

I put it in SQL:

```
With list as 
(select article,part from partlist as e
union all
select article,part from partlist as e inner join liste as l on e.article=l.part)

select article, part from list
```

It looks well:

```
article    | part
-----------+-----------
Article 1  | article 1a 
Article 1  | article 1b
Article 2  | article 1a 
Article 2  | article 2b 
article 2b | article 3a 
article 2b | article 3b
```

But now I want to put two kinds of row numbers on it. One for all rows and one for the parent row.
It should be like this:

```
row | parent row | article    | part
----+------------+------------+-----------
0   | null       | Article 0  | article 1
1   | null       | Article 0  | article 2
2   | 0          | Article 1  | article 1a 
3   | 0          | Article 1  | article 1b
4   | 1          | Article 2  | article 1a 
5   | 1          | Article 2  | article 2b 
6   | 5          | article 2b | article 3a 
7   | 5          | article 2b | article 3b
```

I tried `row_number` but it was not the right sql-query.

Comment: I added a bit of formatting to your question. I hope I didn't misunderstand something. Can you please check?

Comment: and you tagged this with mysql because...?